# Reference a string filter from object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to apply a filter to the output of an angular ng-repeat.  Here's an example of the data:

```
{name: "followers", label: "Followers", filter:"number:0"},
{name: "following", label: "Following",filter:"number:0"},
{name: "mediaCount", label: "Media Count",filter:"number:0"}
```

The display of things looks like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in rows">
<div class="col col-gh-4"><label>{{item.label}}</label></div>
<div class="col col-gh-2" ng-bind="item.value ? (item.value|{{item.filter}}) : '-'"></div>
```

I am trying to apply the filter in this case "number:0" as defined in the data object at display-time using something like: *item.value|{{item.filter}}* or *item.value|item.filter*

Both of those attempts don't work, any advice on how to reference the filter from the object value?  Is it possible?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: to use a custom filter, you need to create one first.

Comment: The 'number' filter exists its how to apply that filter coming from a string in an object...  The goal being for each object element to have a different formatting filter applied.

Comment: Your above code does work: http://plnkr.co/edit/DlwLnZo32Htr4Sfoi3RM?p=preview